# Can I build a fireplace over my LVP?

Tags: walls, flooring, fireplace

We're going to be building out a fireplace wall in our family room and currently have LVP laid down. The new wall will come out from the existing wall 6-9" and will be about 80" wide. The question is whether I am able to install the new wall, which will house an electric fireplace and tv, without cutting out the LVP. My first thought is that since it's a floating floor it needs to come out, but if not necessary I'd love to skip that step.

Answer (score 3):

Circular saws and oscillating tools will make short work of the LVP,. so doing it right isn't prohibitively hard.

That said I've seen internal walls installed over carpet. so you can possibly get away with it. however LVP is not supposed to be attached and installing a wall on top of it will break that rule, so there's a risk of seams opening up...

Comment: "doing it right" is always the best option.